# Inconsistent behaviour from SDL_BlitSurface

Tags: c, sdl

Here is an example code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    {
        printf("SDL ERROR: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Surface *screen;
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(128, 128, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    SDL_Surface *img;
    img = IMG_Load("./debug.png");

    SDL_BlitSurface(img, NULL, screen, NULL);
    SDL_Flip(screen);

    SDL_Delay(1000);

    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I run it sometimes it works and most times only part of the image is displayed. I really can't imagine what's causing that...

EDIT:
This is the image I'm using to test the program:

[image: img]

Comment: Is the image available somewhere? Or can you post a link to an unmodified version?

Comment: I've just edited and put a link to the image....

Comment: I found this: http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1397

Looks like the problem in not the code then...

Comment: OS? SDL and SDL_image versions?

Comment: This happened when I was using Ubuntu 12.04 (gnome). All libs were the most recent version of the package manager, unfortunately I can't remember the number exactly.

Now I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 and the problem is gone...

Answer (score 0):

If debug.png is in the same folder as your main.cpp, just call IMG_Load("debug.png"), there's no need for the ./ at the front.

Just as an aside., there's nothing wrong with initialising your surfaces on one line:

```
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(128, 128, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
//and
SDL_Surface* img = IMG_Load("debug.png");
```

Comment: I know. I'd do that in real code, but I did that just to make things clear... Since something is going wrong i like to make everything very simple and clear...